# ejabberd ldap authentification - user unable to log in

Tags: ldap, authentication, ejabberd

I'm new to ejabberd Server Administration.

I am able to log in with Administrator credentials (Who is mentioned as ldap_rootdn) but I am unable to log in with any of the other Users AD credentials

There will be an Error message in ejabberd.log:

```
2019-06-13 17:08:21.037 [warning] <0.524.0>@ejabberd_c2s:process_auth_result:275 (tls|<0.524.0>) Failed c2s PLAIN authentication for user@server.domain.local from 192.168.xx.xx: Invalid username or password
```

My Config:

```
Host: Windows Server 2016 (Build 1607)

ejabberd: V19.05

Client: Windows 10 (Build 1803)

Gajim: V1.1.3
```

Users are in AD at:

```
OU=Users,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=local
```

Admin in AD is at:

```
CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local
```

ejabberd.yml:

```
language: "de"
hosts:
  - "server.domain.local"

auth_method: [ldap]
ldap_servers: ["dc.domain.local"]
ldap_encrypt: none
ldap_port: 389
ldap_base: "DC=domain,DC=local"
ldap_rootdn: "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"
ldap_password: "xxxxx"
ldap_uids: ["sAMAccountName"]
ldap_filter: "(memberOf=*)"

loglevel: 5
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 1000

certfiles:
  - "C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"

ca_file: "C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 1883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
  lan:
    ip:
      - "192.168.x.0/24"
  admin:
    user:
      - all

access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
    - allow: lan
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
    - allow: lan    
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
    - allow: lan
  trusted_network:
    - allow: loopback
    - allow: lan

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 100
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:xxxx"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: "https://@HOST@:5443/upload"
  mod_last: {}
  ## mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    ## assume_mam_usage: true
    ## default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      ## mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - "flat"
      - "pep"
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      "storage:bookmarks":
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

Any idea, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: ldap_filter: "(memberOf=*)" was the fault. AD Users didn't have this attribute. Changing it to ldap_filter: "(objectClass=user)" did the trick and will be sufficient for my needs...

Answer (score 0):

You can change `ldap_filter: "(memberOf=*)"` to `ldap_filter: "(objectClass=user)"`.

This solved the problem in my case.